# Need help with controls

Tags: emulation, nes, super-mario-bros

I'm currently playing [Super Mario Frustration](https://www.emurom.net/us/emulation/nintendo-roms/detail-61337-super.mario.forever.frustration.html) on my NES emulator.

I'm struggling with some controls. I don't know how to make a jump that looks like [this](https://youtu.be/in6RZzdGki8?t=256) and [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=in6RZzdGki8&t=268). I couldn't replicate it no matter what.

I need some hints. How should I press buttons (A, B, up, down, left, right) to make these jumps?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This question seems a little opinionated and so it may be closed due to that, however, as with many romhacks, it's about learning the engine more than the particular romhack.

Answer (score 1):

As each romhack is more and more unique (Super Orb Bros is a standout SMB3 romhack that does new VERY well), it takes very fine-grained understanding of the height of jumps and running.

Some pointers I had to take away from Super Mario World, which is many iterations and a different engine but still worth noting comes from NES engine are:

- Fluttering - re-grabbing run in the air in order to extend a jump
- Re-grabbing - release and re-pressing a button.
- Speed Jump - a P-speed jump which grants an additional tile in height

It's also worth noting that long-pressing **jumps** grant higher tiles than light taps.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if the first two are possible in the original SMB. Anyway, thanks for the answer but I already found the way to beat the level without any jumps.

Comment: @JimmyYang Be sure to accept an answer. But yeah, experimentation is 9/10 for playing these romhacks.